# Compare two VAT numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I`m trying to list only the vat numbers which look like DDDDDDDDDLLDDDD else i have to list NULL https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PYR8.png

```
case when o.VAT_NUMBER= TO_char(o.VAT_NUMBER, '999999999LL9999') then o.VAT_NUMBER
    else 'NULL' end as VAT_NUMBER,
```

Pretty sure that I`m close but still missing something :(

Comment: Please edit your question to have sample data and current/expected results as formatted text, not images. Is LL supposed to be a literal 'LL', or a currency code, or one of many currency codes - i.e. what specific values are allowed for those two character positions? You're also using `9` for the format model - so it the length actually variable, or fixed and zero-padded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `^\d{9}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$` to match the start-of-the-string, then any 9 digits, then any 2 upper-case letters, then any 4 digits and, finally, the end-of-the-string:

```sql
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( o.VAT_NUMBER, '^\d{9}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}$')
THEN o.VAT_NUMBER
ELSE NULL
END as VAT_NUMBER
```

If you want any case then use `[a-zA-Z]` or `[[:alpha:]]` or make the match case-insensitive.

*Note: If you do not include the start- and end-of-the-string in the match then you could match a sub-string in the middle of the string and not the entire string.*

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with VAT numbers you use. If I got it correctly, it seems that value you're looking for contains 9 digits followed by 2 Ls (?) followed by 4 digits. Oracle docs say that "L" stands for *local currency symbol* (that's RP in your case), so - for sample data

```
SQL> with test (vat_number) as
  2    (select '786633632R97685' from dual union all
  3     select '121015206R77405' from dual union all
  4     select '567299566RP9332' from dual
  5    )
```

you could try

```
  6  select vat_number,
  7         case when regexp_like(vat_number, '\d+{9}RP\d+{4}') then vat_number
  8              else 'null'
  9         end as result
 10  from test;

VAT_NUMBER      RESULT
--------------- ---------------
786633632R97685 null
121015206R77405 null
567299566RP9332 567299566RP9332

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same but if we have different value from RP :(

Comment: Well, only one currency is local for your country. If it is not just RP but some other values, you'll have to have the list of valid strings so that you could validate whether values you find are valid or not.